# Over the value of a definite integration (and over the integration itself)

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I have to perform this definite integration:

$$I = \int_0^{+\infty}\ \text{arctanh}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{e^{1+x^2}}}\right)\ \text{d}x$$

I tried with a naive substitution

$$z = 1 + x^2 ~~~~~ \text{d}x = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{z-1}}$$

obtaining

$$I = \int_1^{+\infty} \frac{\text{arctanh}(e^{-z/2})}{\sqrt{z-1}}\ \text{d}z$$

Which doesn't lean me anywhere. I tried with series expansion but the hyperbolic arctangent is hellish.

**What I do know**

According to Matematica $I = 0.825951$ but I have no clue how to proceed. Are there some useful substitutions/approximations for this kind of integral?

Comment: Do you mind me asking what is the motivation behind calculating this rather unnatural integral?

Comment: In your last formula, I believe the $e^{z/2}$ should be $e^{-z/2}$

Comment: @Cheese Right, I missed a minus whilst writing, thanks :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integration by parts brings that integral into the slightly better form:

$$ I = \int_{0}^{+\infty} x^2 \frac{\exp\left(-\frac{1+x^2}{2}\right)}{1-\exp(-(1+x^2))}\,dx $$
and by expanding the integrand function as a geometric series, then computing $\int_{0}^{+\infty} x^2 \exp\left(-\frac{2k+1}{2}(1+x^2)\right)\,dx $ by usual means, we get:

> $$ I = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2e}}\cdot\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{1}{e^k (2k+1)^{3/2}} $$

where the last series is very fast-converging.

Comment: Uhhh! This is brilliant!

Comment: @Jack, well done! (+1)
The last sum is a Lerch transcendent, just in case u are interested!